# Spark Version 3.3.0 connect with kafka

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to my Kafka from spark but getting an error:
Kafka Version: 2.4.1
Spark Version: 3.3.0

I am using jupyter notebook to execute the pyspark code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
#import library 
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 pyspark-shell'

sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('Pyspark_kafka').getOrCreate()
df = sc \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "ext_device-event_10121") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .option("endingOffsets", "latest") \
        .load()
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-409d93832e70> in <module>
      5         .option("subscribe", "ext_device-event_10121") \
      6         .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
----> 7         .option("endingOffsets", "latest") \
      8         .load()

/opt/spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    467             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    468         else:
--> 469             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    470 
    471     def json(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    194                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    195                 # JVM exception message.
--> 196                 raise converted from None
    197             else:
    198                 raise

AnalysisException:  Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".
```

Not sure what's wrong with the connector or the code please help me out.

**EDIT : 1**
I looked up for the similar postst on stackoverflow and found out that I need to include the kafka client in the OS Environ so replaced the os env with the following:
`--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.1`

Still the same error.

Comment: Don't use `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb

Comment: Did you find out how to solve it? i have the same prob

Comment: @Kaoutar I couldn't, I simply run my pyspark applications using spark-submit

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master('local[1]')\ #for example
    .appName('your_app')\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would remove this line unless it is very critical for your project.

```
.option("endingOffsets", "latest") \
```

Second you need to cast the values as string

```
values = df.selectExpr("CAST(key as string)", "CAST(value as string)").as[String, String]
```

Just to print the incoming data

```
values.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("append").start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: This doesn't address the error in the question. Also, question is asking about Python